# How do I get my CSS grid centered?

Tags: html, css

I am just trying to figure out how to position this grid on the page - I am getting this white space on the left and underneath, not sure where from. I am including a lot of the CSS and relevant grid code. There's also an external stylesheet that might have something on it that's making it do this, but I have gone over it and don't think so. Anyone know what might be causing this? Did I design the grid incorrectly and somehow skip to the second column, or is this margin space? Just trying to get grid somewhat centered, with an even margin around it. Sorry if I do something wrong format-wise or posted too much code - haven't posted in a while (also running on four hours of sleep). Thanks.

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm89M.png)

```
<style>

html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  text-indent: 50px;
  font-size: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-family:'y14.5m-20092009';
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   background-color: white;   
   overflow: auto; 
   margin: 0px;
}

div#furtheroptions {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div#fixedfooter {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  color: #ba2337;
  background:#333;
  padding:8px;
  font-family:'y14.5m-20092009';
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    color: #ba2337;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none; /*keeps blue selection border off*/
}

.navigationbuttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #ba2337;
  width: 100%;
  font-family:'y14.5m-20092009'; 
  margin-right: 100px;
}

    .box {
      background-color: #ba2337;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 150%;
    }
    .a {
        grid-column: col / span 4;
        grid-row: row / span 3;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: col / span 4;
        grid-row: row 4 / span 3;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: col / span 1;
        grid-row: row 7;
    }
    .d {
        grid-column: col 2 / span 2;
        grid-row: row 7;
    }
    .e {
        grid-column: col 4;
        grid-row: row 7;
    }
    .f {
        grid-column: col / span 1;
        grid-row: row 8 / span 1;
    }
    .g {
        grid-column: col 2/ span 2;
        grid-row: row 8 / span 1;
    }
    .h {
        grid-column: col 4 /span 1;
        grid-row: row 8 / span 1;
    }
    .i {
        grid-column: col 1/ span 2;
        grid-row: row 9 / span 3;
    }
    .j {
        grid-column: col 3 /span 2;
        grid-row: row 9 / span 3;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<form>
<div class="navigationbuttons">
<div class="box a">A</div>
<div class="box b"><font size=300px>B</font></div>
<div class="box c">C</div>
<div class="box d"><font size=5>D</font></div>
<div class="box e">E</div>
<div class="box f">F</div>
<div class="box g" style="text-align: center"><input type="text" name="search"  placeholder="Search.."></div>
<div class="box h"><button type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.google.com';"</button>Button 1</div>
<div class="box i"><button type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.google.com';"</button>Button 2</div>
<div class="box j"><button type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.google.com';"</button>Button 3</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't get you. can you explain a bit . what exactly you are looking for

Comment: The "left" thing comes from `display: grid`.

Comment: @PatrickMlr Why's that?

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: center;`on `.navigationbuttons`.

Comment: That's great! It's centered but left a ton of space on left, right, bottom. Will have to look into how to just set the grid size bigger. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin-right` from `.navigationbuttons` and add `justify-content: center`

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  text-indent: 50px;
  font-size: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'y14.5m-20092009';
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}

div#furtheroptions {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div#fixedfooter {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ba2337;
  background: #333;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: 'y14.5m-20092009';
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  color: #ba2337;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  /*keeps blue selection border off*/
}

.navigationbuttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #ba2337;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'y14.5m-20092009';
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ba2337;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.a {
  grid-column: col / span 4;
  grid-row: row / span 3;
}

.b {
  grid-column: col / span 4;
  grid-row: row 4 / span 3;
}

.c {
  grid-column: col / span 1;
  grid-row: row 7;
}

.d {
  grid-column: col 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 7;
}

.e {
  grid-column: col 4;
  grid-row: row 7;
}

.f {
  grid-column: col / span 1;
  grid-row: row 8 / span 1;
}

.g {
  grid-column: col 2/ span 2;
  grid-row: row 8 / span 1;
}

.h {
  grid-column: col 4 /span 1;
  grid-row: row 8 / span 1;
}

.i {
  grid-column: col 1/ span 2;
  grid-row: row 9 / span 3;
}

.j {
  grid-column: col 3 /span 2;
  grid-row: row 9 / span 3;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="navigationbuttons">
    <div class="box a">A</div>
    <div class="box b">
      <font size=300px>B</font>
    </div>
    <div class="box c">C</div>
    <div class="box d">
      <font size=5>D</font>
    </div>
    <div class="box e">E</div>
    <div class="box f">F</div>
    <div class="box g" style="text-align: center"><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."></div>
    <div class="box h"><button type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.google.com'">Button 1</button></div>
    <div class="box i"><button type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.google.com';">Button 2</button></div>
    <div class="box j"><button type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.google.com';">Button 3</button></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if that is your code, you have quite a lot of unclosed HTML tags.

Then if you want the grid centered in the page the easiest thing to do is to give a class to the container of the grid (the form tag in this case, but you can also create a new one just under the form) and give it these rules:

```
.centeredGrid {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[A working example is here](https://run.plnkr.co/6C4fCyk7iJVYHdIp/)

The size is depending on the input field `width` that in your case is `400px`.

The complete code (fixed also with the closed HTML tags) is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dbtv76TpvDICEzQjlLAg?p=preview)

You can also use `display: flex` instead of table, but remember that [flexbox is not supported in IE9 and lower and for IE10 and IE11 you have to use the vendor prefix](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex).